# How to characterize a Backward Euler Method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I know the difference between the forward (explicit) Euler method and backward (implicit) Euler method in the context of approaching solutions to ODEs.

However, I have a doubt regarding the following method:

$$y_{n+1}=y_n+\frac{h}{2}(f(t_n,y_n)+f(t_{n+1},y_{n+1}))$$

I am not sure whether it is an implicit or an explicit method.

I tend to say it is implicit one step methode because we have to solve an equation to calculate $y_{n+1}.$

Thank you for your help.

Comment: To be more specific, this is the implicit trapezoidal or trapezium method. It can be seen as an instance of a Runge-Kutta method or a linear multi-step method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're quite right.

An *explicit* method is given by $y_{n+1} = F(t_n,y_n)$, with no mention of $y_{n+1}$ on the RHS, and you can compute $y_{n+1}$ directly.

An *implicit* method is given by $F(t_n,y_n,y_{n+1})=0$, and you have  to solve an equation to find $y_{n+1}$.

Both these definitions are for *one-step* methods: $y_{n+1}$ depends directly or indirectly just on $t_n$ and $y_n$, not on any $y_k$ for $k<n$.

Comment: @Ihf Can we consider it as a one step method? I am puzzeled by the $(h/2)$ and wonder if that is rather a 2 step method? Thanks

Comment: @PerelMan, see my edited answer.